Spring Security and Application Logic
I’m moderately familiar with Spring-boot and have built somewhat of a Todo application. I’m having an issue and I’ll try my best to explain it. I have a model class, when the authenticated user logs in, I want them to be able to access their todos. Within this model class, I want to utilize a field from the user object, i.e., username. I want that username to be the current logged in user or the principle. Such that they can read and write their todos. Seems pretty simple but perhaps I’m overthinking the implementation. If you have any better ideas in performing the same logic, please help and/or advice.
Shown below are my security configurations:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityBasicAuthConfig {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SpringSecurityBasicAuthConfig.class);

//  @Autowired
//  private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService user;

//  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication) throws Exception {
//      authentication.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
//  }

    /* The below code block allows access to the H2 console */
//  @Bean
//  public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
//  return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/h2/**", "/api/v1/registration/**");
//  }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        String methodName = "filterChain";
        logger.info("Executing, " + methodName);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/registration/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority("USER")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
       @Bean
       AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() 
       {
           DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
           provider.setUserDetailsService(user);
           provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
           return provider;
}
}

@Entity 
@Table(name = "item") 
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private String description;
    private String completionDate;
    private String isDone;
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column("user")
    @JoinColumn
    private User user;
    
    public Item() {
    
    }
    
    public Item(Long id, String description, String completionDate, String isDone, User user) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.completionDate = completionDate;
        this.isDone = isDone;
        this.user = user;
    }
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    public String getCompletionDate() {
        return completionDate;
    }
    
    public void setCompletionDate(String targetDate) {
        this.completionDate = targetDate;
    }
    
    public String getIsDone() {
        return isDone;
    }
    
    public void setIsDone(String isDone) {
        this.isDone = isDone;
    }
    
    public Long getUser() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Item other = (Item) obj;
        return id == other.id;
    }
}


Why did you add .requestMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()? I hope you don't have something like that in production...

So you have somewhat described an approach you are using. So what issues are you facing? What exactly are you looking for by writing this question? Are there any problems with your current approach?

Yes, the problem is I don't know what to get the current logged in User.

What you want is usually what is done, mostly using a customized Authentication object holding all the relevant data required for simple user interaction like displayname or whatever. Don't overload it, just use the bare minimum for quick access, everything else should be retrieved from the db on demand.

If you don't know how to implement this by now, you might wanna take some lessons in Spring Security. I don't know if it's allowed to recommend a Udemy tutorial, if not any moderator is free to delete this comment, but I was very happy with Mick Knutson's Spring Security Master Class. It's a bit outdated, but the principles are still the same. He tackles exactly what you need. Btw: Udemy has every few weeks special prices for their courses, so you might wanna keep an eye for that.
